# Start sequence on a variable column without "array not expanded" error?

Tags: google-sheets

In one sheet, I have columns for each month. In another sheet, I define `start countdown in:` with a cell `04/2023` and `# of months` as `4`.

The desired result is starting under April 2023, I want to see a countdown of 4, 3, 2, 1.

I can use the formula `=sequence(1, Rules!$B$26 + 1, Rules!$B$26, -1)` but only if I manually add it under April 2023.

I tried doing `=if(text(B1,"MMyyyy")=text(Rules!$B$25,"MMyyyy"),sequence(1, Rules!$B$26 + 1, Factors!$B$26, -1),)` for all the cells in the row, but it gives the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data"

Comment: Error states that there are values   already in one or more cells that your formula would overwrite.  Clear those cells the error will go away.

Comment: That’s the question. Each cell has a formula to check if the month matches the starting month, then start the sequence. Otherwise I would have to manually go to the month and add the formula there.

Comment: The question is not clear to me  however you should not cross post multiple Stack-Exchange sites.  Please remove this one since it is asked and [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76117961/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for those searching:

```
=index(xlookup(A$1:L$1,edate(N2,sequence(O2,1,0,1)),sequence(O2,1,O2,-1),))
```

Full example seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117961/start-sequence-on-a-variable-column-without-array-not-expanded-error/76118094#76118094